# How does Maven interpret groupId and artifact

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have the following dependency in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.usenet.node</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.usenet.node.exchange.data.json</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I get this error when compiling :
**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project communication-bundle: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.usenet.btrust:communication-bundle:bundle:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.use
net.node:org.usenet.node.exchange.data.json:jar:0.0.3-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]**

However, i have the needed jar in my local repo. How does maven interpret the groupId and ArtifactId to fid the jar?
thanks

Comment: Well, if it really is in your local repo, it should work, I think. Can you double-check it again (pay attention to typos)? Also consider to delete it from the local repo. Maybe something got corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the Maven coordinates from the jarfile itself, it is listed in the manifest, i.e. META-INF/MANIFEST.MF